SD card that will work reliably on Note 20
I have had an SD card that I have been using for years, over half a dozen phones (all Samsung, as I upgraded the phones).  It suddenly died.
I put in a SanDisk Extreme Pro 1TB (as I had it lying around, never used before),  It only lasted about two weeks and is not responding.
What I am looking for

A brand of SD card that is known to work reliably on Samsung Phones
Atleast 250GB, preferably 500GB+
Reasonable speed to be able to watch movies and record video to it
Price is not that important, looking for value for money.
I am in NZ

What I am using it for

I am not reformatting it, just using it as storage that I can physically shift to a new phone when upgrading.
I had redirected Camera, screenshots etc to it
It holds most of my photos
It holds most of my music and music videos
It holds about 20 movies that I haven't watched yet


Two weeks is suspiciously short. Are you sure it's legit? Flash fraud is quite common sadly. If it is, you should RMA it and get a replacement. Also, do you have speed requirements?

@JMY1000, The card had been in my box for a while, I may be able to find where I bought it from.  On Android site, many users complain that sdcards don't last long on Samsungs, but I have never believed.  Maybe 1TB was too large.  My speed requirement is just to be able to watch movies from it.

Any idea on what the bitrate of those movies are? There are specific high-endurance SD cards, but they are slower and lower capacity.

I can recode them to be lower.  I picked one at random 1406kbps

@RohitGupta, SD cards by design are expendable. The technology have limited cycles of write and the small size do not help much for usage as long term storage. Use SD as just temporary storage and always make backup of the information there.

@RomeoNinov, This question is not about backups.  I always have backups.  Its about finding an SSD card that will last more than a few weeks, incase there are compatibility issues or size limitations.

@RohitGupta, there is difference in schemas of SD and SSD. For me 256GB microSDXC,  SanDisk Ultra, Class 10 UHS-I U1 work fine (but I use it mostly for read operations)

Samsung Pro Endurance 256 GB - $73.07 (NZD)

All NAND flash will die eventually; the question is how long (more specifically, how many write cycles) it takes. There's a fundamental trade off between density and endurance. The good news is that you can buy high-endurance microSD  cards, since there's a large market for them (particularly for use in dashcams.) They aren't going to be super fast (they're all U3/V30 at best, with the Samsung Pro Endurance rated for 100/40 MB/s read/write)—I wouldn't try to put them in an expensive camera and shoot top-quality video—but that should be more than sufficient for watching movies, especially at your bitrate.
Of the various options on the market, the two most available are the Samsung Pro Endurance and the SanDisk Max Endurance. Both are specifically rated for high-continuous writes, with 5-year and 15-year limited warranties respectively. The SanDisk Max Endurance uses TLC cells in pMLC mode; I believe (though I have not fully confirmed) that the Samsung Pro Endurance card uses proper MLC flash. This should theoretically give the Samsung cards a minor edge, but they both should be extremely durable.
That said, I do want to reiterate that "two weeks" is a suspiciously short lifetime; even the crappiest SD cards should last longer than that. Moreover, NAND flash does not suffer substantial wear and tear from read operations, only write operations. Your use case is not particularly strenuous by most standards, and probably does not require a high-endurance SD card. That's not to say that buying one will be "bad", it'll just be a little more expensive, slower, and lower density than buying a "normal" SD card.

I accepted JMY100's answer.  I ended up buying SanDisk Extreme Pro microSDXC 512GB. I just had a feeling that perhaps 1TB was too large for the phone.
I tracked down the source of the SdCard.  It was Temu, so I am writing it off as fake.
